# Product aggregation does not work as expected

Tags: python-polars

I am using the product function of polars.

I have a dataframe with 1458644 rows and one of its column is 'vendor_id' and has unique values = [1,2].

While trying to run the product function on the entire df, it return 0.

However, if i run the product function on unique values it returns 2.

Any reason as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rust knowledge is not great but I think what happens is you end up with `0` during multiplication due to how [`i64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/primitive.i64.html) [behaves in rust](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch03-02-data-types.html):

> When you’re compiling in release mode with the --release flag, Rust does not include checks for integer overflow that cause panics. Instead, if overflow occurs, Rust performs two’s complement wrapping. In short, values greater than the maximum value the type can hold “wrap around” to the minimum of the values the type can hold. In the case of a u8, the value 256 becomes 0, the value 257 becomes 1, and so on. The program won’t panic, but the variable will have a value that probably isn’t what you were expecting it to have. Relying on integer overflow’s wrapping behavior is considered an error.

So in your case, the max of i64 is `2^63 - 1` = `9_223_372_036_854_775_807` (see [`https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i64/constant.MAX.html`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/i64/constant.MAX.html)). When you exceed the max by `1`, number turns into min (which is `-2^63` = `-9_223_372_036_854_775_808`. When you exceed the min by `-1`, number turns into max.

So let's reproduce the steps:

```py
df = pl.select(pl.repeat(2, n=63).alias('vendor_id'))
df.product()

# this is still good
┌─────────────────────┐
│ vendor_id           │
│ ---                 │
│ i64                 │
╞═════════════════════╡
│ 4611686018427387904 │
└─────────────────────┘

df = pl.select(pl.repeat(2, n=63).alias('vendor_id'))
df.product()

# you see now we exceed the max but still within bounds of i64
┌──────────────────────┐
│ vendor_id            │
│ ---                  │
│ i64                  │
╞══════════════════════╡
│ -9223372036854775808 │
└──────────────────────┘
```

Now, what's going to happen if you multiply it by 2 again? Let's split it into steps:

```py
# let's turn multiplication into a sum
res = 2 * -2^63 = -2^63 + -2^63

# instead of substracting 2^63 we subtract 1 first and then (2^63 - 1)
res = -2^63 + -2^63 = -2^63 - 1 - (2^63 - 1)

# we exceed the min by -1 so we end up at max (-2^63 - 1) = (2^63 - 1)
res = -2^63 - 1 - (2^63 - 1) = (2^63 - 1) - (2^63 - 1)

# and now final subtraction
res = (2^63 - 1) - (2^63 - 1) = 0
```

So we ended up exactly at `0`! Now, when you have `0`, whatever you multiply it by you'll have `0` as a result.

We can also try it in rust with this simple code:

```rust
use std::num::Wrapping;

fn main() {
    println!("{}", Wrapping(-9223372036854775808i64) * Wrapping(2i64));
}

-------------
0
```

When you execute `unique()` first you end up with very small dataframe - values are going to be either `[1]` or `[1,2]` or `[2]` - depending of values of your dataframe. So at the end you'll have either `2` or `1` as a result.

```py
df.unique()

┌───────────┐
│ vendor_id │
│ ---       │
│ i64       │
╞═══════════╡
│ 2         │
└───────────┘
```

So question to you would be - what do you expect to get? `2^1458644` (possible max for your operation) will have quite a lot of digits in it.

In your case you don't really need to rely on rust to calculate the result. If you would still expect some reasonable number, you could probably just count amount of rows with `vendor_id = 2` and then use python `pow` function to calculate the result:

```py
df = pl.select(pl.repeat(2, n=100).alias('vendor_id'))
pow(2, df.filter(pl.col('vendor_id') == 2).count().item())

1267650600228229401496703205376
```

Comment: Thanks, i  guess this makes sense. To your question of what i was expecting: Was just exploring polars and wanted to understand how product works, when I ran into this issue.